# Why is CGFloat float on 32 bit and double on 64 bit?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics

From "CoreGraphics/CGBase.h":

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
# define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
# define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
# define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif
```

Why did Apple do this? What's the advantage?

I can seem to think of downsides only. Please enlighten me.

Comment: How is more precision without performance loss a downside?

Comment: Network and persistence code is more complicated, it's taking up double the memory, if I set my compiler warnings to be very strict I get a lot of warnings when using math.h functions.

Comment: For the latter issue, I believe the suggested approach is to use tgmath.h instead of math.h

Answer (score 4):

Apple explicitly says they did it ["to provide a wider range and accuracy for graphical quantities."](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/64BitChangesCocoa/64BitChangesCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH4-SW9) You can debate whether the wider range and accuracy have been really helpful in practice, but Apple is clear on what they were thinking.

It's worth remembering, BTW, that `CGFloat` was added in OS X 10.5, long before iPhones (and certainly long before 64-bit iPhones). Going 64-bit is more obviously beneficial on "big memory" machines like Macs. And Apple made "local architecture" types that were supposed to make it easier to transition between the "old" and "new" worlds. I think it's interesting that Swift brought over `NSInteger` as the default `Int` type (i.e. `Int` is architecture-specific). But they made `Float` and `Double` architecture independent. There is no equivalent of `CGFloat` in the language. I read this as a tacit acknowledgement that `CGFloat` wasn't the greatest idea. NEON only supports single precision floating point math. Double precision math has to be done on the VFP. (Not that NEON was a consideration when `CGFloat` was invented.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a performance thing.

On a 32-bit CPU, a single precision, 32-bit `float` can be stored in a single register, and moved around quickly and efficiently, because it's the same size as an architecture-native pointer.

On a 64-bit CPU architecture, a 64-bit IEEE `double` has the same advantage of being the same size as a native pointer/register/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm also suspecting that performance is part of the answer. But why the extra precision in the first place? Does it actually help in an environment like CoreGraphics?

Comment: CoreGraphics is doing hojillions of floating point calculations for every little draw operation. Even in the face of the document referenced by another answer, I remain highly confident that the use of `double` on 64-bit architectures has *little* to do with the added precision, and *everything* to do with performance. Or, stated differently, if moving from `float` to `double` had a performance penalty, I'm pretty sure they would not have done it.

Comment: There was a lot of discussion at the time that moving to 64-bit could hurt performance. (Apple discusses it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/indications/indications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH206-TPXREF101) Sometimes it was a win, sometimes not. Lots of the wins were in fancy pointer tricks (like sticking NSNumber values in the pointer), having nothing to do with floating point math. It was mostly in my remembrance about being "64-bit is the future" more than "it's going to be faster."